# Changing the filename of an image picked from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsp, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that visits a .jsp page with a button that when pressed requests the user for an existing image or to take a picture, which is just a UIPickerViewController that could maybe be overridden. When the image is selected it is returned to the form of the .jsp page. Is it possible to change the filename of the image that is selected before it is returned to the form of the .jsp page?

UIWebview Init Code

```
    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address/UserImage.jsp", [Utilities getIP]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *objRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:objRequest];
    webView.delegate=self;
```

Before button selection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFGPZ.jpg

After button selection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MLiY.jpg

Comment: I will just assume that this is just not possible since I have not received any feedback...

Comment: Found a solution that is rather crude but works, thanks for your help everybody! MERRY CRAPMAS!!